# Standard ML: Getting Last in List

Tags: recursion, sml

I'm trying to get the last element of a list of integers in SML but I want to indicate (somehow) when the user passes in an unacceptable list (such as an empty one).  My code is here:

```
fun lastInList [] = ~1
    | lastInList [x] = x
    | lastInList (x::xs) =
    lastInList xs;
```

This works on any non-empty list since execution will always hit the second line before the first.  However, is there an idiomatic way of being able to deal with all integers?  I'd like to return some kind of exception, I guess.  Current solution isn't great because -1 can be in my list (obviously).

Thanks for the help,
bclayman

Comment: It sounds like your problem isn't how to get the last element in a list, but how to distinguish a specific result (empty list in this case) from an arbitrary data element in a domain (integers in this case). I recommend rephrasing your question to reflect your intent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always [raise an exception](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_ML#Exceptions):

```
fun last []      = raise Empty
  | last (x::xs) = last' x xs

fun last' x []      = x
  | last' _ (x::xs) = last' x xs
```

Another [option](http://sml-family.org/Basis/option.html) (if you would pardon the pun):

```
fun last []      = NONE
  | last (x::xs) = SOME (last' x xs)

fun last' x []      = x
  | last' _ (x::xs) = last' x xs
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: The idiomatic exception to raise would be the predefined `Empty`, which is also used by other list functions.

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way would be either just to allow the function to fail on invalid inputs:

```
fun last []      = raise Empty
  | last [x]     = x
  | last (_::xs) = last xs
```

Or to use an option type:

```
fun last' []      = NONE
  | last' [x]     = SOME x
  | last' (_::xs) = last' xs
```

This also works for any generic list, not only those of ints.

Comment: Non-exhaustive patterns are highly discouraged. Better raise an exception explicitly.